# Application-defined or object-defined error when using Access 2007 Report Wizard

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

We have a single user who has been having problems with Access 2007.  Specifically, this particular user can open any database, but when they try to use the Report Wizard, at the end of the wizard they are getting the generic error message, "Application-defined or object-defined error".  This is no error number or any further details, but this error happens consistently, regardless of the contents of the report or which database/tables are involved.

Some info that may be pertinent:

1. Most of the database files are stored on a network share.
2. This particular user can use Access on other computers without getting
   the error.
3. It appears that, at one point, Access 2010 was installed
   alongside Access 2007.
4. We have tried repairing the Access 2007 installation but it has not helped.
5. The computer in question last ran Windows updates approximately 6 months ago, at which point Office 2007 Service Pack 3 was installed, along with several other Office 2007-related updates.  This may coincide with when the user first started experiencing these problems, but I can't be sure.

My initial guess is that there is something wonky with the Access 2007 installation, but I don't know exactly what.  Any ideas?

Comment: Some possible solutions here: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Wizards-working-t1799035.html